# Fab on top of lock screen

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2, floating-action-button

Hello friends I am developing an Android app where people can send messages to nearest friends and I want to have a floating action button on top of lock screen. So whenever they click on the fab it will open some activity bypassing the password. Is this possible and if yes then how? Please help. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't know if you can ask activity from lock screen in android! It's possible in iPhone apps.

Comment: You can send push notification which will enable your users to see who are closest and your push notification click will open an activity!

Comment: @ibtehaz I have seen some apps where fab is used to open an activity. Those fabs are placed on top of lock screen. I actually want that kind of mechanism. By the way thanks for ur help